# How do I adjust my function to multiply multiple (random number of) matrices?

Tags: r, function, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have written the following function for multiplying two matrices `A` and `B`:

```
f <- function(A,B){
       m<-nrow(A)
       n<-ncol(A)
       n<-nrow(B)
       p<-ncol(B)
       Result<-matrix(0,nrow = m,ncol = p)
       for(i in 1:m){
         for(j in 1:p){
           for(k in 1:n){
             Result[i,j]<-Result[i,j]+A[i,k]*B[k,j]  
             }
           }
         }
       return(Result)
       }
```

How would I adjust my function code to multiple 3 or more, i.e., a random number of matrices rather than just 2?

Comment: Not sure what you are really doing, but why don't you use `R`s matmul operator `%*%`? Then something like ``Reduce(`%*%`,list(A,B,C))``.

Comment: Hmmm, I've seen similar code today... Giving us homework questions, are we?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just iteratively apply two-matrix multiplication. Let `f` be the fundamental function multiplying two matrices `A` and `B`. Normally we use the internal one `%*%`, but you can use the one defined in your question.

Since the number of matrices are unknown, I suggest using `...`. We collect all matrices input into a "matrix list" by `list(...)`, then use `Reduce` to cumulatively apply two-operand matrix multiplication.

```
g <- function (...) Reduce(f, list(...))
```

Note, it is your responsibility to ensure the matrix dimension are conformable, especially when you have a lot of matrices. In the following, I would just use square matrices as an example.

```
set.seed(0)
A <- matrix(rnorm(4),2)
B <- matrix(rnorm(4),2)
C <- matrix(rnorm(4),2)
f <- "%*%"

g(A, B, C)
#          [,1]        [,2]
#[1,] -3.753667  0.08634328
#[2,] -0.161250 -1.54194176
```

And this is as same as:

```
A %*% B %*% C
#          [,1]        [,2]
#[1,] -3.753667  0.08634328
#[2,] -0.161250 -1.54194176
```